# Compare an ArrayList of HashMaps, determine which row has the highest value of a specific key

Tags: java, hashmap

This is going to be hard to explain but I will try my best.

I have a data file in excel where each row is a separate entry. The data file keeps track of all versions of the one entry so there are multiple rows for a single unique item and there can be multiple items. Below is an example of the data set:

The first value (apples,pear,grape) is the unique value that I want to group by and the last value is the version number in which I only want the latest (highest number).

```
row1 apples,computer,1
row2 apples,laptop,2
row3 apples,tablet,3
row4 pear,tablet,1
row5 pear,tablet,2
row6 grape,tablet,1
```

What I am looking for is the below: I have taken the latest version of each group (based off the unique identifier - first field)

```
row1 apples,tablet,3
row2 pear,tablet,2
row3 grape,tablet,1
```

Right now I have a method that reads the excel file and places each row of data in an arraylist (`ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`) entry which has a hashmap to map the field name (column heading) and the value. All fields are String.

```
row1(fieldName1:apples,fieldName2:computer,fieldName3:1)
row2(fieldName1:apples,fieldName2:laptop,fieldName3:2)
row3(fieldName1:apples,fieldName2:tablet,fieldName3:3)
row1(fieldName1:pear,fieldName2:computer,fieldName3:1)
row2(fieldName1:pear,fieldName2:laptop,fieldName3:2)
row3(fieldName1:grape,fieldName2:tablet,fieldName3:1)
```

fieldName1 would be the unique identifier and fieldName3 would be the version Number
Any ideas or thoughts on how I would go about doing this? Let me know if you need any clarifications!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing with that input in hashmap... How do you get the data from excel and how do you parse them into your program?

Comment: Are you using a HashMap to store field values, almost like what you'd do in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the column and comparator to compare in the way you're looking for. If you switch from a Map to a proper class, again, all you need to do is tweak the comparator. Just be aware that, in this case, `Long.valueOf` could throw an exception if your column didn't contain a long.

```
final String column = "foo";
Map<String, String> max = Collections.min(table, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String, String> o1, Map<String, String> o2) {
        long l1 = Long.valueOf(o1.get(column).trim());
        long l2 = Long.valueOf(o2.get(column).trim());
        return Long.compare(l1, l2);
    }
});
```